# knockout is not updating observebles within extend functions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockout to show in a span the value from an extend function.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: clientName" />
<span data-bind="text: clientName.dummy"></span>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
Model = function() {

//MyExtension definition
ko.extenders.MyExtension = function(target, options) {
    target.dummy = ko.observable('hello');

    target.subscribe(function(newValue){
        target.dummy = ko.observable(new Date().toString());
        target.dummy.notifySubscribers(); //this shouldn't be necessary
    });

    return target;
};

this.clientName = ko.observable().extend({MyExtension: "some options here"} );

};

myModel = new Model()
ko.applyBindings(myModel);
```

Since "dummy" is itself an observable, the behaviour I was expecting is:

```
1) User changed input box text
2) knockout trigers the subscribe function (and this is hapening)
3) dummy value is updated with current time (happens to)
4) The span's text is updated with last dummy value (this is not happening)
```

Any idea why?
Thanks.

PS: Here is the full test: http://jsfiddle.net/AYLv8/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding your `dummy` property with a new completely new observable in the your `subscribe` function.

The correct implementation would be to update the `dummy` observable:

```
target.subscribe(function(newValue){
    target.dummy(new Date().toString());
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Qcv6/).